# Java sql like sqlite

Tags: java, database

I created an android app. and I used sqlite to keep my small files. When I use sqlite, I could create tables, and did operations with just a java class.
Now I am creating pure java application, and I need small database that can be created with programmatically on java application like android sqlite. 
Is there any java database like sqlite ?

Comment: You can use [`MySQL`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) database.

Comment: mysql needs host probably, I want not host depended one

Comment: This might help http://blog.rungeek.com/post/81611917/how-to-use-sqlite-with-java. It is using `SQLite` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use Sqlite, also you could use H2 which has similar features.